# DAO for fetching organizations and departments through a REST API

Tags: java, beginner, generics, rest

I have the following class structure:

```
public class CustomDAOImpl implements CustomDAO {   

    public List<Organization> getOrganizations() {
        List<Organization> results = new ArrayList<Organization>();
        Client client = ClientHelper.createClient(); 
        Resources<OrganizationResource> response = client
                .target(restApiRoot + "organizations")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .get(new GenericType<Resources<OrganizationResource>>(){
                });
        List<OrganizationResource> resources = response.getContent();
        for (OrganizationResource resource : resources) {
            results.add(resource.getEntity());
        }
        return results;
    }

    public List<Department> getDepartments() {
        List<Department> results = new ArrayList<Department>();
        Client client = ClientHelper.createClient();
        Resources<DepartmentResource> response = client
                .target(restApiRoot + "departments")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .get(new GenericType<Resources<DepartmentResource>>(){
                });
        List<DepartmentResource> resources = response.getContent();
        for (DepartmentResource resource : resources) {
            results.add(resource.getEntity());
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

The abstract class :

```
public abstract class ResourceSupport {
    @XmlElement(name="link")
    private List<Link> links;
}
```

Entities :

```
public class DepartmentResource extends ResourceSupport {
    @XmlElement(name="department")
    private Department entity;

    public Department getEntity(){
        return entity;
    }
}

public class OrganizationResource extends ResourceSupport {
    @XmlElement(name="organization")
    private Organization entity;

    public Organization getEntity(){
        return entity;
    }
}
```

I'm new to JAVA, so I am not familiar enough with generics.

How can I improve my approach to have cleaner more elegant code?

The code must compile in JAVA 7 platform.

**EDIT**

I tried something like this :

```
private <T, U> List<T> makeRequest(Class<T> clazz1, Class<U> clazz2, String path) {
    List<T> results = new ArrayList<T>();
    Client client = ClientHelper.createClient(); 
    Resources<U> response = client
            .target(restApiRoot + path)
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .get(new GenericType<Resources<U>>(){
            });
    List<U> resources = response.getContent();
    ...
    return results;
}
```

invoke like this :

```
List<Organization> list = makeRequest(Organization.class, OrganizationResource.class, "organizations");
```

But i have now an java.lang.ClassCastExceptionjava.lang.ClassCastException:

```
Source : java.lang.reflect.Method cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
  at com.owlike.genson.reflect.TypeUtil.getTypes(TypeUtil.java:397)
  at com.owlike.genson.reflect.TypeUtil.match(TypeUtil.java:331)
  at com.owlike.genson.convert.BasicConvertersFactory.provide(BasicConvertersFactory.java:97)
  ...
  at com.owlike.genson.Genson.provideConverter(Genson.java:155)
  at com.owlike.genson.Genson.deserialize(Genson.java:387)
  at com.owlike.genson.ext.jaxrs.GensonJsonConverter.readFrom(GensonJsonConverter.java:122)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the advise of a person from reddit here : [Java code refactoring, in order to get rid of code duplication](https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/58niho/java_code_refactoring_in_order_to_get_rid_of_code/)

I tried something like this :

```
private <T0, T1 extends ResourceSupport<T0>> List<T0> getResources(Class<T0> clazz1, Class<T1> clazz2, String path, GenericType<Resources<T1>> genericInstance ) {
    List<T0> results = new ArrayList();
    Client client = ClientHelper.createClient(); 
    Resources<T1> response = client
            .target(restApiRoot + path)
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .get(genericInstance);
    List<T1> resources = response.getContent();
    for (T1 resource : resources) {
        results.add(resource.getEntity());
    }
    return results;
}


@XmlRootElement
@Getter
@Setter
public class OrganizationResource extends ResourceSupport<Organization> {

    @XmlElement(name="organization")
    private Organization entity;

    @Override
    public Organization getEntity() {
        return entity;
    }
}


@XmlRootElement
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class ResourceSupport<T>  {
    @XmlElement(name="link")
    private List<Link> links;

    public abstract T getEntity();
}
```

Called like this :

```
GenericType<Resources<OrganizationResource>> genericInstance = new GenericType<Resources<OrganizationResource>>(){};
List<Organization> list = getResources(Organization.class, OrganizationResource.class, "organizations", genericInstance);
```

For information, the rest api response is :

```
{
  "links": [],
    "content": [
        {
            "organization": {
                "id": "GES",
                "code": "GES",
                "name": "GES XX1",
                "legalNumber": "654654654"
            },
            "links": [
              {
                  "rel": "self",
                  "href": "https://server:8443/api/organizations/GES"
              },
              {
                  "rel": "organizations",
                  "href": "https://server:8443/api/organizations"
              },
            ]
        },
        {
            "organization": {
                "id": "PRO",
                "code": "PRO",
                "name": "PRO XX1",
                "legalNumber": "54545646"
            },
            "links": [ ... ]
        ...   
    ]
}
```